# How to create a form that updates continouisly without "freezing" the window

Tags: vb.net, forms

OK, So I am trying to create a minor VB.NET program that applies and monitors values in another application, and I am running into a snag that I cant seem to find an answer to.

I would like a separate Form, or part of the same form, pull values from the other program [not a problem] analyze them and display their status. The problem is that any time I use a form to achieve this, I find that the window that this changing text is located in becomes functionally unresponsive to the user, with the mouse wheel spinning, and being unable to access any controls located on that form (other buttons, minimize close, or the ability to click to bring it to the front/resize the window).

I am currently using a background worker that has a dowork method that displays a form and then updates the text labels on it and then refreshes the form in a loop. This loop can be canceled by the changing of a public shared variable. I can clearly see the text is being updated with the values, but the form is unresponsive otherwise.

Is there any way around this? I would like the form to behave as a regular application window and be resizable/closeable while still showing real.

Here is a sample of my code with bits that could be compromising or whatever redacted:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Public Shared notbroken = 1 'Break the killer loop

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Ok Button

        Button1.Hide() 'Stop user from clicking the button again.

        Dim choice

        'show which button is selected in each case
        Dim regenType As RadioButton = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
        Dim regenVariant As RadioButton = moving.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)

        'Assigns a number from the selection to these once the ok button is pressed.

        mainmethod(choice)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        notbroken = 0

        If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub mainmethod(regenchoice As Integer)
        'Main Logic
        'Project.Online = True 'TODO - Uncomment

        AssignHandles()

        CollectOrRestore("collect") 'Collect values to restore upon reopen

        'Recorder.Start

        RunRegen(regenchoice)

        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = True Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If

        'SaveRecording

        'CloseProj()

    End Sub


    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Form3.Show()

        Do While Form1.notbroken
            Form3.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

            ' Sample of how Im reporting status
            Form3.Label2.Text = "Text String: " & statusOfTextStringCheck() 

            Form3.Refresh()
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            Label1.Text = "Canceled!"
            Refresh()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Label1.Text = "IN CASE OF EMERGENCY: "
            Form3.Close()
            Button1.Show()
            Return
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            Label1.Text = "Error: " & e.Error.Message
            Refresh()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Label1.Text = "IN CASE OF EMERGENCY:"
            Form3.Close()
            Button1.Show()
            Return
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Done!"
            Refresh()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Label1.Text = "In Case Of EMERGENCY:" & e.Result
            Form3.Close()
            Button1.Show()
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseProj()
        Dim x = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to close the project?" & vbCrLf & ":Initial Values will be restored.", 65, "ClearVision")
        If x = 2 Then Return
        CollectOrRestore("restore") 'Restore Initial Values
        release()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Background worker shouldn't do anything with form, especially when you are putting it to sleep. Delete most of you intro and post more code and we will fix it.

Comment: Is this more helpful @Claudius? Also: is there is any way to use anything other than the background worker to have a separate continuously updating form? I would really like to know! I saw tons of information warning against this, but if I keep it on the same thread all of the controls (understandably) lock up, so I suppose this is a temporary solution...

Comment: Put thread.sleep for 500 in do work and delete thread sleep from work completed. Plus I saw you had progress bar which background worker supports out of box.

Comment: I made some changes,thanks for the help on the progress bar, that I can probably add to the main form! Any other suggestions for the form updating without freezing?

Comment: yes. refere to links http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo The problem is your logic, form3 show shouldn't be in dowork

Answer (score 0):

Here I put together a quick example of how to use the Background worker in a form. Number one rule is not to set any UI elements in the background worker, instead send the changes though the ProgressChanged event of the Background worker and make the changes on the UI thread.

Sample Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click

        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then

            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdEnd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdEnd.Click
        _bCancel = True
    End Sub

    Private _bCancel As Boolean = False

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        Dim iIteration As Long = 0
        Do Until _bCancel
            iIteration += 1
            Dim sTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
            Dim sStatus As String = "Iteration Status " & iIteration.ToString()
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, New WorkProgress(sTime, sStatus))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Loop


    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim act As Action(Of System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) = AddressOf HandleProgressChanged
            Me.Invoke(act, e)
        Else
            HandleProgressChanged(e)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleProgressChanged(e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)

        Dim progress As WorkProgress = DirectCast(e.UserState, WorkProgress)

        lblTime.Text = progress.TimeText
        lblStatus.Text = progress.Status

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

    End Sub

    Public Class WorkProgress

        Public TimeText As String
        Public Status As String

        Public Sub New(sTimeText As String, sStatus As String)
            TimeText = sTimeText
            Status = sStatus
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```